# Auto populate kendo box using jquery selector

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have multiple tags like the below in my HTML.

```
<li data-code="ABC"
<li data-code="XYZ"
<li data-code="PQR"
```

I need to add the three values to a kendo auto complete box.

```
<input id='myKendobox'/>
```

I used the below code to get the list.

```
var items = $("li").map(function () { return $(this).attr("data-code"); }).get();
```

I have two questions:
How to I make sure the fourth empty item doesn’t come in the “items” list?
How do I populate the items in my kendo auto complete box?

Answer (score 1):

Your `li` items are not closed, did you realize?

For populating the autocomplete you might do:

Given the input HTML (autocomplete):

```
<input id='myKendobox'/>
```

and the initialization as follow:

```
var data = [];
var autocomplete = $("#myKendobox").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataSource: data
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
```

When you want to add the elements you do:

```
var items = $("li").map(function () { return $(this).attr("data-code"); }).get();
autocomplete.dataSource.data(items);
```

If you want to limit the `<li>` elements found by your jQuery selector you might define them as:

```
<ul id="AutocompleteOptions">
    <li data-code="ABC"></li>
    <li data-code="XYZ"></li>
    <li data-code="PQR"></li>
</ul>
```

and then change the selector to:

```
var items = $("li", "#AutocompleteOptions").map(function () { return $(this).attr("data-code"); }).get();
```

This restricts the `<li>` found to only those under `#AutocompleteOptions`.

Example running in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/BhLEJ/)